# How to use support library graddle.app in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to make a To-Do app in Kotlin. I opened the Android Studio. 
What is the reason for this difference?

> Android Studio version: Android Studio 3.5
>   Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
>   JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit 
>   Windows 10

My Gradle Scripts :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

This is the script in the video I watch:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Comment: The above dependencies are for androidx and video must be old cause according to video it's using sdk version 27.

Comment: why do you need Support Library? This are deprecated and unusable from API level 29. `AndroidX` is the future. You will get everything from `AndroidX` that you need

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7OoPPti8XI0) 
I'm trying to do the thing in this video. But there are differences. How can I overcome these problems? How do I make the application in the video?

Comment: I suggest you watch another video. The tutorial uses outdated code and doesn't follow best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library):

> **Note:** With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new
>   version of the support library called [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) which is part of
>   Jetpack. The **AndroidX** library contains the existing support library
>   and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts
>   (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*)
>   will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library
>   development will occur in the AndroidX library.
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You
>   should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.